# How can we show the preview image of the video in table view cell?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I have a table view and if we touch a cell a video plays. I need to show the preview image of the video in the UITableViewCell. I have kept some dummy image in the cell at image place and remaining space ion cell is with some labels and buttons. I need the image preview of the video with play symbol on it. How can I make this ? Should I use any photoshop type of things or any programable things. I do not know photoshop.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the preview by displaying the preview image of your video. Once you add preview image, add sub view as button with play button image.

i.e..

previewImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,imageW,imageH)] autorelease];

previewImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

previewImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"videoPreview.png"];

[cell.contentView addSubview:previewImage];

playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

playButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,buttonWidth,buttonHeight);

[playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cell.contentView addSubview:playButton];

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Jim.

Comment: Thank you Jim. I am trying on it now.